# related to win 64bit or not? error: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: c++

does anyone know if this error is related to win64 or is there something wrong with my code please ? 
On window 10 - 64bit, I'm running gcc version egcs-2.91.57 19980901 (egcs-1.1 release) -- which I think is for 32bit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_STUDENT = 3;
typedef struct student{
    char name[50];
    char classID[15];
    int age;
};
student student_list [MAX_STUDENT]; 
int student_position = 0;

void add_new(){
    if (student_position == MAX_STUDENT) {
        student_position = 1;
    }
    else {
            student_position++;
    }
    cout << "student name:  " <<  endl;
    cin >> student_list[student_position].name;
    cout << "student classID:  " <<  endl;
    cin >> student_list[student_position].classID;
    cout << "student age:  " <<  endl;
    cin >> student_list[student_position].age ;

}
void list(){
    for(int i = 1; i < student_position+1; i ++){
        cout << i << "/name: " << student_list[i].name << " - classID: " << student_list[i].classID << " - age: " << student_list[i].age <<  endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char command = 'a';
    cout << "please input command: N (New), L (List), E (Exit), W(Write to file)." <<  endl;
    while(cin >> command){
        switch (command) {
            case 'N':
                add_new();
                break;
            case 'L':
                list();
                break;
            case 'E':
                return 0;
            default:
                cout << "wrong command" <<  endl;
                break;
        }

    };
    return 0;
}
```

then the error occurred for the third time input student information:

> ```
> [main] D:\1.books\0.C++_Primer\student.exe 1000 (0) handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
> [main] student 1000 (0) handle_exceptions: Dumping stack trace to student.exe.core
> ```

p/s: I add the stack trace:

```
[main] student 1000 (0) exception: trapped!
[main] student 1000 (0) exception: code 0xC0000005 at 0x407E23
[main] student 1000 (0) exception: ax 0x330000 bx 0x330000 cx 0x418348 dx 0xA
[main] student 1000 (0) exception: si 0x0 di 0x401000 bp 0x246FEA8 sp 0x246FEA4
[main] student 1000 (0) exception: exception is: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: Stack trace:
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 0: sp = 0x246F830, pc = 0x6100A2C3
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 1: sp = 0x246F86C, pc = 0x7783EAC2
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 2: sp = 0x246F890, pc = 0x7783EA94
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 3: sp = 0x246F95C, pc = 0x7782C6B6
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 4: sp = 0x246FEA8, pc = 0x407AB1
[main] student 1000 (1) stack: frame 5: sp = 0x246FED0, pc = 0x4011A2
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 6: sp = 0x246FEE4, pc = 0x401637
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 7: sp = 0x246FF00, pc = 0x61004402
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 8: sp = 0x246FF48, pc = 0x61004420
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 9: sp = 0x246FF54, pc = 0x41772E
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 10: sp = 0x246FF64, pc = 0x40103A
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 11: sp = 0x246FF80, pc = 0x77318484
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 12: sp = 0x246FF94, pc = 0x77822FEA
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 13: sp = 0x246FFDC, pc = 0x77822FBA
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: frame 14: sp = 0x246FFEC, pc = 0x0
[main] student 1000 (0) stack: End of stack trace
```

Comment: That dumped stack trace you chose not to include will have the *exact* code path for where the wheels fell off this wagon. Follow it to your code and you'll find the problem. I can tell you this: Stop fighting zero-based indexing and *embrace* it. Your life will be much, *much* easier if you choose to stick with this language.

Comment: thank you WhozCraig, I saw the dumped stack trace but couldn't understand it, could you give me some advices for this trace please :

Comment: How about you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51721093/edit) and include it in your message dump so we can all see it. And remember, *embrace zero-based indexing*.

Comment: Well, thanks for the update. now, compile with debugging enabled. If compiled from the command line using mingw, gcc or clang, use the `-g`  command line switch. And did I mention *zero-based indexing* is what's for dinner?

Comment: yes, WhozCraig, thank you !!
I compile from the command line using gcc, my command is: g++ -o student student_test.cpp -g

Comment: I'm trying to understand this:

D:\1.books\0.C++_Primer>g++ -o -g student student_test.cpp

/cygnus/cygwin-b20/H-i586-cygwin32/i586-cygwin32/bin/ld: cannot open student: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The `-g` belongs nearly *anywhere* but where you put it; put it *before* the `-o` option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177544/discussion-between-zoro-and-whozcraig).

Comment: egcs 1.1 is [from 1998](https://gcc.gnu.org/egcs-1.1/). You're trying to use a gcc version that's literally twenty years old. Why?!

Comment: yahh, I'm new to C ++, don't know what is the best yet, just followed this guide found from google: www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html

Comment: @zoro Why that page in particular? It says it was last updated in 2005, so it's more than 13 years old. That's not quite Windows 95/98 anymore, but it's still the Windows ME / XP era.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexing is wrong.

Both C and C++ utilize *zero-based indexing*. That means native arrays of dimension `N` are accessible using indexes `0..(N-1)`. You `student_position` should flag the apparent rollover back to zero you seem to be seeking upon encountering an insert request when it has already attained the maximum array dimension. And the loops for display should run from zero to the dimension, strictly *less-than* on the top end (therefore complying with `0..(N-1)` indexing.

See below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_STUDENT = 3;
struct student
{
    char name[50];
    char classID[15];
    int age;
};
student student_list [MAX_STUDENT];
int student_position = 0;

void add_new(){
    if (student_position == MAX_STUDENT) {
        student_position = 0; // HERE
    }

    cout << "student name:  " <<  endl;
    cin >> student_list[student_position].name;
    cout << "student classID:  " <<  endl;
    cin >> student_list[student_position].classID;
    cout << "student age:  " <<  endl;
    cin >> student_list[student_position].age ;

    ++student_position; // HERE

}
void list(){
    for(int i = 0; i < student_position; ++i){
        cout << i << "/name: " << student_list[i].name << " - classID: " << student_list[i].classID << " - age: " << student_list[i].age <<  endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char command = 'a';
    cout << "please input command: N (New), L (List), E (Exit), W(Write to file)." <<  endl;

    while(cin >> command){
        switch (command) {
            case 'N':
                add_new();
                break;
            case 'L':
                list();
                break;
            case 'E':
                return 0;
            default:
                cout << "wrong command" <<  endl;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That will solve the problem of the fault, but leave you with the task of determining whether your wrap-logic is accurate. I suspect it isn't, but that isn't what this question is about.

Comment: thank you WhozCraig, actually I have successfully run the program with that index started from 0, but since I wanted to show the correct list of student with correct index (start from 1, not 0), then it led to my problem.
Thank you, I will take note about this. !!